# ChartImg.axd error in ASP.NET 3.5.2

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a webapp in ASP.NET framework 3.5.2.

After draging the Chart Control from the toolbox to where I want it in my .aspx page, there seems to be this added at the top of the document:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

When I run I get the error: "Error executing child request for ChartImg.axd."

I have tried adding the following into system.web in my Web.config

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>
```

Then I get:

> HTTP Error 500.23 - Internal Server Error
>
> An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.
>
> Most likely causes:
> •This application defines configuration in the system.web/httpHandlers section.

It says that I can try to "Migrate the configuration to the system.webServer/handlers section".

How do I do this and how till it affect my webapp? Will something else stop working and is it possible to revert the migration?

Answer (score 1):

With ASP.NET 3.5 projects where I got this error I went into IIS and changed the APplication Pool to run in **Classic** Managed Pipeline Mode rather than **Integrated**

To change this go to :IIS, go to Application Pools, Find the pool you're using and change it to Classic.